# How do I get the value of a variable in a function inside a private function in a class?

Tags: php, class, function, variables

I have a PHP class like the following

```
<?php
class Test{
  var $conf = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, c => 3);

  private function do_something(){
    // Do something Here
    function do_something_else(){
      // How to get the variable value for $conf ???? o.O
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I want to access `$conf` inside the function `do_something_else()`. In the upper level functions I am able to access this as `$this->conf`, but I guess `$this` would not be available in the inner function. What would be the best possible way to access the variables inside that function?

I cannot pass the values as this function would be called by a built-in function in WordPress CMS, so passing arguments can not be a choice here.

Comment: Please don't. Nested functions may **look** clean, but they are not. Nested functions are the same as normal functions (i.e. they're global), but are only defined when the parent function gets called. So again, please don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you need is anonymous function, here is some solutions.
You can do in PHP 5.3:

```
 class Test{
    var $conf = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);

    private function do_something(){
        // Do something Here
        $that = $this;
        $do_something_else = function() use($that) {
            echo $that->conf;
        };

        $do_something_else();   
    }
}
```

Or use `$this` directly on [anonymous](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) function but only PHP 5.4.

Comment: +1 Anonymous function closures is, as far as I know, the only way to achieve what he wants.

Comment: This looks promising, m checking it, thanks for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

Why not keep it simple

i.e

```
<?php
class Test{
  private $conf;

  private function _construct()
  {
     $this->conf = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, c => 3);
  }
  private function do_something_else(){
      // How to get the variable value for $conf ???? o.O
      // NOW THIS BIT IS EASY $this->conf;
  }
  private function do_something(){
    // Do something Here

  }
}
?>
```

Comment: ...except then you afaik can't use `do_something_else()` as a callback from something that doesn't know about the `Test` class.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - The question did not specify this. Even so use an interface. Simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: The question states that the function is to be called from a built-in Wordpress function, that would require changing Wordpress to accomodate the interface or making an extra layer of "bridge code". Better in the long run, perhaps, but not a solution without its own pains.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson - Granted - but Wordpress is open source and needs people to make it better. (But IMHO Wordpress is c**p)